# Extracting block of data from string nested between zeros

Tags: regex

I need a regex that can get a block of code that is nested between zeros.

For example if I have:

0000000000000000000000000000000000000000089504E470D0A1A0A0000000D49484452000002A10000013D0802000000B48C2CAC000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000097048597300000EC300000EC301C76FA864000006DE49444154785EEDDBD191DB380C00D0F4937AD24FEAD97AB69F3B8BA42412046DED8D27EB9CDFFB330502909401ED4CF2030000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

I need the regex to return:

89504E470D0A1A0A00000000D49484452000002A10000013D0802000000B48C2CAC000000017352474200AECE1CE90000000467414D410000B18F0BFC6105000000097048597300000EC300000EC301C76FA864000006DE49444154785EEDDBD191DB380C00D0F4937AD24FEAD97AB69F3B8BA42412046DED8D27EB9CDFFB330502909401ED4CF203

I have tried `([A-F 1-9])+` however it leaves gaps where there are zeros between the block of code. I am new to regex and know that the regex above wont capture the zeros in between however I am unsure of how to continue from there.

This is all hex data if it helps.

Comment: What language will you be running this pattern in?

Comment: @mickmackusa Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, but you don't want the middle characters to exclude `0`:

```
[A-F1-9][A-Z\d]+[A-Z1-9]
```

Comment: This works in JavaScript but it is giving me problems in Java. Is there a simple way of translating it to Java regex?

Comment: I tested it with an online Java Regex tester. Perhaps the issue is getting the (literal) backslash into the string? You can replace `\d` with `0-9` instead.

Comment: I figured out the problem, thank you! I just replaced \d with \\d